# Why didn't Axios send Authorization Header automatically in HTTPS? JWT's

Tags: reactjs, authorization, redux, jwt, axios

Made a react/redux app. The server side would serve up a jsonwebtoken upon user credentials, and I would receive it in the browser. No problems at all.

Locally. Everything was going well. I had express-jwt as a middleware blocking all /api routes. When I checked my dev tools and looked under the Network tab, Authorization header was being sent on EVERY request because I used

```
const ROOT_URL = "https://**myappname**.herokuapp.com";

axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}` ;
```

The localStorage even still says that it has the token, and I can still see it in the local storage. However, when I'm in the browser in PRODUCTION, for some reason from now on, this axios.defauls.headers thing isn't working anymore.

Weird. So I just ended up saying forget it, deploying process has been taking just as long as freaking building the app. Removed express-jwt out of frustration.

Any reason why this stopped working? Did it have to do with a buildpack setting? That's the only thing that I can imagine that changed.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, have you got the answer for your question yet? I'm facing the same problem here.